# merge multiple sql queries

Tags: mysql, join

In the header of the pages of my site, I have multiple SQL queries. For example:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT blah2 FROM misc WHERE id='1'", $db);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result); $blah2 = $rs[blah2];

$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_bans WHERE IP='$ip'", $db);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result) != 0) { header("Location: banned.php"); }

$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='$un' AND pw='$pw'", $db);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result); 
// do all account login check etc

$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'", $db);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result); 
// get members data
```

..and more.

All this info is needed for each page of my site. Is there a way to combine these, or just limit the ammount of queries? I'd imagine this would get quite intensive on the database over time.

I'm not too good with JOINs and things, is that what i need?

Comment: " I'd imagine this would get quite intensive on the database over time" Its tough to say without measuring since its hardware and DB size dependent. If you have enough memory it might not be a problem at all because its always getting the data from RAm

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `UNION`.
Here is a good tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlunion.php

I would recommend you to only use it where it's "natural" and not merge to many different queries.

Comment: it says here "In order to perform a UNION the columns of table 1 must match those of table 2." Each of my tables is different though, so can i use it?

Comment: I don't think a UNION would work, since the columns and types are probably different for each query.